# Javascript not displaying strings with " ' " in them

Tags: javascript

I am writing a Javascript function where strings with apostrophe ( ' ) are not being displayed. Is there a way I can go around this? The below function assumes x is a string.

```
function addItem(x, y) //adds item on screen and adds Total
    {
        var newRow = "<tr><td>"+x+"</td><td>€"+y.toFixed(2)+"</td><td><input type=\"button\" onclick=\"subtract("+y+")\" value = \"X\"></td></tr>"
        $('#order').append(newRow);

        document.getElementById("currentorder").value += newRow;

        //Adds Total Value
        var total = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
        total = parseFloat(total);
        var z = +y + +total;
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=z.toFixed(2);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JS console? Are the strings present in the HTML (check using Inspect Element)? It might just be a case of needing to escape special characters in the content you're writing into `innerHTML`

Comment: Just before you insert `x` into `newRow`, replace  apostrophe( ' ) with `&rsquo` in `x`

Answer (score 0):

**Confusing Addition Operators**

The following line looks quite a bit off :

```
var z = +y + +total;
```

If you just want to add `y` and `total`, just simplify it as :

```
var z = y + total;
```

**Consider Possible Parsing Errors**

Another idea would be to consider stripping out any non float related characters (i.e. non decimals and digits) within your string prior to calling your [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function :

```
var total = parseFloat(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML.replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''));
```

Comment: I suppose that's a likely assumption, however it almost resembles a likely "typo" scenario that might be missing another argument. Just wanted to ensure that wasn't the case.